# React map through json object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops, object

I am having trouble finding a way to iterate through this nested JSON data.
I would like to display elements into select option list.

I store my data in a state after a request.

```
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    ScenarioService.getFilterData().then((res) => {
      setFilterData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    });
    setIsData(true);
  }, []);
```

```
{
"groups":[
      "group1",
      "group2"
   ],
"regions":[
      "region1",
      "region2"
]
}
```

I already tried:

```
<select>
      {Object.keys(filterData).map((key) => {
         return filterData[key].map((value) => {
           return <option>{key[value]}</option>;
         });
       })}
</select>
```

```
<select>
{Object.keys(filterData["regions"]).map((keyName, i) => {
   return (
     <option key={filterData[keyName]}>{filterData[keyName]}</option>
   );
})}
</select>
```

```
{filterData.regions.map((value)=>{
          return <option>{value}</option>
        })}
```

Last one gives my TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

If i try to set my state to setFilterData(res.data.regions) then i can call map() and it works, but then my state is only regions.

Result should look like:
[image: result]

Comment: looks like you're way overcomplicating. You just need, for the first select, `filterData.groups.map(...)`, where `...` is a simple function to wrap the text in an `<option>`. (Similar to the ones you already have.) Similar for the second one, just using `regions` instead of `groups`.

Comment: If i try your solution i get error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" because i can not map through Object. I dont really know why it is happening because groups is array and it should work with map(). @RobinZigmond

Comment: I just looked again, it's because your `filterData` starts off, before the request resolves, as an empty array - and it needs to have those 2 properties. Try replacing `const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState([]);` with `const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState({ groups: [], regions: [] });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify the code duplication by using a function

```
const renderOpts = key => filterData[key].map(v => <option value={v}>{v}</option>)
```

Then to render the selects:

```
<select>{renderOpts('groups')}</select>

<select>{renderOpts('regions')}</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.